# Creating Multiple host file in Ansible

Tags: ansible

Is it possible to create multiple host file in Ansible. These files are getting created dynamically.

```
New host file name is A,B and C
```

I want to do ssh into a machine which is present is B. How my ansible will understand the host file B for logging into the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for the `-i` switch to specify hosts file?

```
ansible host_name_in_B -i hosts_file_B -m setup
```